# How can I show that: $\text{Tr}(A^*A)=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(A^*A)}\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, hermitian-matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$, how can we show that:
$$ ||A||^2_F=\text{Tr}(A^*A)=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(A^*A)}\lambda$$

Where $A^*=\bar A^T.$

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So much unexplained notation. What is $\mathbb K$: the set of compact operators on some space?  If you are only asking the question about matrices (two of the tags are for matrices), not operators on some infinite-dimensional space, then observe that the *only* role of $A$ is in the product $A^*A$, so allow a general square matrix $M$: do you know why ${\rm Tr}(M)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $M$? The sum should have eigenvalues counted *with multiplicity*.  For example, ${\rm Tr}(I_n) = n$ but $I_n$ has 1 as its only eigenvalue, so you need to add 1 to itself $n$ times (not just 1 time).

Answer (score 2):

The trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues, up to multiplicity. As $A^*A$ is Hermitian, it is diagonalisable, hence there is an invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$, whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A^*A$, up to multiplicity, such that
$$A^*A = P^{-1} D P.$$
Using the fact that $\operatorname{Tr}(CD) = \operatorname{Tr}(DC)$, we get
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A) = \operatorname{Tr}(P^{-1} D P) = \operatorname{Tr}(DPP^{-1}) = \operatorname{Tr}(D),$$
which is the sum of the diagonal entries of $D$, i.e. the sum of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ up to multiplicity.

Here are two things worth noting:

1. The notation $\sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A^* A)} \lambda$ could be misleading, in that it doesn't make it clear that eigenvalues must be summed **up to multiplicity**. For example, if $A = I_{2 \times 2}$, then $A^*A = I_{2 \times 2}$, which has **one** eigenvalue of $1$, up to a multiplicity of $2$, i.e. $\sigma(A^* A) = \{1\}$. One could reasonably interpret the sum as simply $1$, when the trace of $A^*A$ is actually $1 + 1 = 2$.
2. The fact that $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues up to multiplicity is true for any matrix, even non-diagonalisable matrices. We may not be able to get a diagonal matrix $D$, but we can get an upper-triangular matrix $D$ (e.g. the Jordan Normal Form).